# How to parse nested xml in pyspark

Tags: python, xml, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following xml document

```
<a date="26-03-2018" id="1">
<text>
</text>
<metadata>
<b>
<c c="STRING1">
<d="value" e="string"/>
</c>
<c c="STRING2">
<d="value2" e="string" />
</c>
</b>
</metadata>
</a>
```

By using data bricks xml parser,I want to extract the `string1`,`string2` values of `c` as a list to the `column[metadata]` of dataframe but when I infer with custom schema

```
schema = StructType([
StructField("date", StringType(), True),
StructField("id", LongType(), True),
StructField("text", StringType(), True),
StructField("metadata", StructType([
StructField("b", StringType(), True)]), True),])
```

and the dataframe for the above schema

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Id | date       | text | metadata 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | 26-03-2018 | text |' <c c="STRING1"> <d="value" e="string"/></c><c c="STRING2"><d="value2" e="string" /> </c>'
```

I am getting the entire data as string from `b` node. Any ideas on how to extract only strings using databricks xml parser to the column named metadata or is there any other parser available. I couldn't find the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rdd to parse and ElementTree library.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

row_counter = Row('columnName1', 'columnName2', 'columnName3')

def parser_xml(string_xml):
   root = ET.fromstring(string_xml.encode('ISO-8859-1', errors='replace'))
   ''' Implement all parser logic
   '''
   columnName1 = root.find('test').attrib['value1']
   columnName2 = root.find('test2').attrib['value2']
   columnName3 = root.find('test3').attrib['value3']

   return row_counter(columnName1, columnName2, columnName3)

rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("/files/*.xml")
data = rdd.map(lambda (string_file): parser_xml(string_file[1])) 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=None, samplingRatio=None, verifySchema=True)
df.write.parquet('output')
```